# HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, vhosts

I am setting up a site for testing using apache 2.2. I editted the host, vhost.conf and httpd.conf files to include the name of my website and the directory of the files but everytime I try to open it on IE 8, it says HTTP 403 Forbidden. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: More details please.  What page are you navigating to?  Does this work in any browser, or just not in IE8? Can you paste the <VirtualHost> directive block from your httpd.conf?

Comment: Is this only happening on IE8? Have a look if the folder is readable or executeable for the user running apache (maybe www-data?). Set chmod to 777 *for testing purpose*. If it works, you know it's a user right problem and can work from there.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot C:/vhosts/AppStore
   ServerName appstore
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to say without seeing more of your configuration files, but to start: Are you sure your web server has access to the directory you're using (e.g., is it a directory under your server root -- or does it otherwise have the correct permissions)?

Comment: You are right, my directory was not under my server root. I had to change my document roots in my httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions on the files correctly? I have run into the same kind of problem when the actual directory holding the files doesn't have the permissions set correctly.